# Css Arrow with dashed border

Tags: html, css

I'm Trying to get my `:before` arrow work nicely with my `div`, but i can't find a way to give the arrow

- `background-color: transparent`
- `dashed border`.

[image]

CSS:

```
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 12px dashed transparent;
  border-left: 12px dashed #b3b3b3;
  border-bottom: 12px dashed transparent;
  border-left-color: #b3b3b3;
  content: '';
```

**[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KCqyk/)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use same border-width and rotate the pseudo element.
Add a background to hide the box border where it stands. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KCqyk/1/)**

CSS can become for the pseudo :

```
ul.timeline li.item-timeline:nth-child(even):before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 37px;
    right: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-top: 1px dashed #b3b3b3;
    border-right: 1px dashed #b3b3b3;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    transform:rotate(45deg);
    background:white;
    z-index:1;
    content:'';
}
```

*Use prefix wherever it is needed.*

---

Extra infos,

if the buggy dotted radius border in FF bothers you, you can play with an outline-offset to cut into borders.**[DEMO, for FF only](http://jsfiddle.net/KCqyk/2/)**

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    /* a stupid way to fix here the border radius effect when dotted or dashed*/
    div.inner-content {
        outline:white double 4px;
        outline-offset:-5px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the idea from this code http://codepen.io/romanstrobel/pen/EgCHi. You can't use the :before though, because of different z-indexes

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="arrow"></div>
  <div class="arrow-cover"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap {
  margin: 100px auto;
  width: 300px;  
  height: 150px;    
  position: relative;
}
.arrow {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 3px dotted gray;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -25px;
  left: -25px;
  z-index: 10;
  border-radius: 10px;  
}
.arrow-cover {
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -25px;
  left: -21px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  z-index: 30;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.box {
  width: 300px;  
  height: 150px;    
  background: white;
  z-index: 20;
  position: relative;
  border: 3px dotted gray;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```